# can't escape + in elastic search query

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, tokenize, n-gram

I am unable to escape + symbol from my query string, I tried both ways 1) using \ and 2) by quoting the string. Also while tokenizing any string with + symbol generates tokens which don't have + sign. I am using token characters as
"token_chars":["letter", "digit", "punctuation", "symbol"]. Surprisingly - symbol is working perfectly fine and is getting escaped. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: I think you only use a single backslash. Try doubling it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't work

Comment: As mentioned by @WiktorStribiżew `"string\\+to search"` should work. Can you tell me the field(s) on which query is applied and what is the type and analyzer(s) (if type is `text`) of the field?

Comment: @NishantSaini the type is text and the analyzer used is default analyzer with token characters as letter, digit, punctuation and symbols

Comment: Are you using NGram/Edge NGram tokenizer as token filter in your default analyzer? Can you share the exact definition of the analyzer being used and the field mapping?

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with the tokenizer which is ignoring + symbol to create tokens . I tried adding math_symbol to token chars but it didn't work

Comment: "tokenizer":{
        "my_ngram_tokenizer":{
          "type":"ngram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":40,
          "token_chars":["letter", "digit", "punctuation","symbol"]
        }

Comment: "analyzer":{
        "default":{
          "tokenizer":"my_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter":["lowercase"]
        }  @NishantSaini

Comment: I tried you analyzer for input `a+b` and resulted in generating following tokens: `a+`, `a+b`, `+b`. So it might have something with the query. Share your query with sample docs and expected result.

Comment: Can you please tell which version of elastic search you are using @NishantSaini ,i am currently using 5.4 version

Comment: I tried on version 6.4

Comment: looks like a version problem to me then , i am not able to tokenize any query having '+' sign with '+' in the generated tokens